# Can i choose which Grub

Tags: grub2

G'Day;  I have Ubuntu 15.10 on one partition and Ubuntu Mate 15.10 on another partition, is there some way I can choose which grub boot loader is used, I want to use the Mate bootloader..

Comment: Since you are just running different desktop flavors of the same release (and therefore download every update twice), did you know that you can install most of the flavors by installing the corresponding  [metapackage](http://askubuntu.com/q/65083/40581)? It's [mate-desktop-environment](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/mate-desktop-environment) for Mate. [Then just switch on the lock screen.](http://i.imgur.com/zwHfn6O.png)

Answer (score 2):

Serg is (sort of) correct. If the output of `cat /etc/fstab` includes a line that mentions `/boot/efi`, you're booted in EFI mode (proceed to EFI). If it says something like "not found", or just outputs nothing, you're not in EFI mode. (proceed to BIOS)

**EFI**

This will be a list of commands to run, run them from top to bottom:

```
sudo grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=ubuntumate --target=x86_64-efi --recheck --debug

sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntumate/grub.cfg
```

(I don't know if boot/efi/EFI/ubuntumate will be the path where GRUB is installed, you may want to do `sudo ls /boot/efi/EFI` and figure out if it's in GRUB or ubuntumate)

**BIOS**

Do `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

Answer (score 0):

Boot from Mate and run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Reference : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154940/set-which-grub-loader-to-use-after-dual-booting-two-linux-oses